# Smart hard wrap for list of items in vim

Tags: vim

I love vim, and I really like to hard wrap my texts when I write them. The markdown plugin from Tim Pope is great, and is build such that when I try to hard wrap a list of items it does the job right. Ok here is what I mean by doing the job right:

```
- here I write a long long long line that is longer than the 80 caracters of a line and therefore should be wrapped.
- This is a short line
- here I write another long long long line that is longer than the 80 caracters of a line and therefore should be wrapped.
```

should become (after applying gqap):

```
- here I write a long long long line that is longer than the 80 caracters
  of a line and therefore should be wrapped.
- This is a short line
- here I write another long long long line that is longer than the 80 caracters
  of a line and therefore should be wrapped.
```

Now, the behaviour of the same command for a text with a tex filetype is not that smart:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item here I write a long long long line that is longer than the 80 caracters I fixed and therefore should be wrapped.
\item This is a short line
\item here I write another long long long line that is longer than the 80 caracters I fixed and therefore should be wrapped.
\end{itemize}
```

becomes (still after a gqap):

```
\begin{itemize} \item here I write a long long long line that is longer than
        the 80 caracters I fixed and therefore should be wrapped.  \item This
        is a short line \item here I write another long long long line that is
        longer than the 80 caracters I fixed and therefore should be wrapped.
\end{itemize}
```

How can I make the wrapping of the list of items in LateX behave like the markdown list?

To me it looks like I should redefine the syntax file, but I have no idea how (the way markdown works is by using the elements defined for HTML).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### config

```
:set fo+=n
:let &flp='^\s*\\\w*\s*'
```

---

#### input

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item here I write a long long long line that is longer than the 80 caracters I fixed and therefore should be wrapped.
    \item This is a short line
    \item here I write another long long long line that is longer than the 80 caracters I fixed and therefore should be wrapped.
\end{itemize}
```

---

#### type

<kbd>gggqG</kbd>.

---

#### output

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item here I write a long long long line that is longer than the 80
          caracters I fixed and therefore should be wrapped.
    \item This is a short line
    \item here I write another long long long line that is longer than the 80
          caracters I fixed and therefore should be wrapped.
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: As I wanted to have only item related commands to be defined as list items, I used the following command :let &flp='^\s*\\\(item\|end\|begin\)*\s*'

Comment: I tweaked it a little bit to gracefully handle commands inside hard wrapped paragraph: `let &l:flp='^\s*\\\(item\|end\|begin\)\s*'`